# all updated columns turn to zero

Tags: csv, updates

I use below script to update the csv file but it will set all 2nd coumn to zero

```
cat file_0.csv notZero.csv > update.csv
```

file_0.csv

```
"m01";"0";"yyy";"zzz"
"m02";"0";"yy";"zzz"
"m03";"0";"y";"zzz"
```

and the notZero.csv

```
"m02";"5";"yy";"zzz"
"m04";"7";"yyy";"zzz"
"m05";"8";"yy";"zzz"
"m06";"9";"y";"zzz"
```

expected output

```
"m01";"0";"yyy";"zzz"
"m02";"5";"yy";"zzz"
"m03";"0";"y";"zzz"
"m04";"7";"yyy";"zzz"
"m05";"8";"yy";"zzz"
"m06";"9";"y";"zzz
```

"

Comment: Why do you expect the m02 row from file_0 to not show up in your output?

Comment: I expect if their first columns is same then it updates the second column, but all rows of two file must be exist in update.csv I used join -a1 file_0.csv  notZero.csv > update.csv but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` gets you a long way, but you have to specify the field separator character as well:

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -t';' notZero.csv file_O.csv
```

which gives

```
"m01";"0";"yyy";"zzz"
"m02";"5";"yy";"zzz";"0";"yy";"zzz"
"m03";"0";"y";"zzz"
"m04";"7";"yyy";"zzz"
"m05";"8";"yy";"zzz"
"m06";"9";"y";"zzz"
```

Note the order of the input files, so that any matched fields will have the non-zero value first.

To get rid of the extra fields, you can use `cut`:

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -t';' notZero.csv file_O.csv  | cut -d';' -f1,2,3,4

"m01";"0";"yyy";"zzz"
"m02";"5";"yy";"zzz"
"m03";"0";"y";"zzz"
"m04";"7";"yyy";"zzz"
"m05";"8";"yy";"zzz"
"m06";"9";"y";"zzz"
```

But for any more advanced combinations, I suggest to avoid the shell and shell commands, and use a more sophisticated language.